# DataTables - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: javascript, json, datatables

I've seen several examples of this problem but still haven't been able to find a resolution.

The error says it breaks on jquery.dataTables.js (version 1.10.4) on line 3287 shown below

```
// Got the data - add it to the table
    for ( i=0 ; i<aData.length ; i++ ) {
        _fnAddData( settings, aData[i] );
    }
```

This is my controller. The controller is this way because the the lack of db connection right now, but will have JSON returned in the same format as $data. I have tried several things to resolve the error, but keep running into other issues. The JSON IS valid.

```
public function test()
{
  $data = '{"persons": [{"branch": "CORP","phone_numbers": [{"desk": "5223422117"},{"mobile": "5022319224"},{"branch": "422-922-2291"}],"email": "twilliams@test.com","preferred_name": "Thomas","person_id": 368,"department": "IT","first_name": "Thomas","title": "Programming Manager","last_name": "Williams"}]}';

  $data = json_encode($data);
  echo $data;

}
```

My javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('#directory_table').dataTable( {
         "ajax": {
             "url": "test",
             "type": "JSON"
         },
         "aoColumns": [
             { "persons": "preferred_name" },
             { "persons": "last_name" },
             { "persons": "phone_numbers.0" },
             { "persons": "phone_numbers.1" },
             { "persons": "phone_numbers.2" },
             { "persons": "email" },
             { "persons": "department" },
             { "persons": "title" }
         ]
     } );
 } );
```

My HTML

```
<table id='directory_table' class="display">
    <thead>
        <tr style='background: #186A9F; color: white;'>
            <th>First Name </th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>Desk Number</th>
            <th>Mobile</th>
            <th>Branch</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Department</th>
            <th>Title</th>
        </tr>
    <thead>
</table>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### CAUSE

By default DataTables expects JSON response to have certain structure, see [documentation](https://datatables.net/manual/ajax).

Array of arrays:

```js
{
    "data": [
        [ "value1", "value2" ],
        ...
    ]
}
```

Array of objects:

```js
{
    "data": [
        {
           "attr1": "value1",
           "attr2": "value2"
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```

Error occurs because name of the data property in your response holding array of objects (`persons`) differs from default (`data`).

#### SOLUTION

Use [`ajax.dataSrc`](http://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.dataSrc) option to define the property from the data source object (i.e. that returned by the Ajax request) to read.

```js
$('#directory_table').dataTable( {
   "ajax": {
      "url": "test",
      "dataSrc": "persons"
   },
   "columns": [
      { "data": "preferred_name" },
      { "data": "last_name" },
      { "data": "phone_numbers.0.desk" },
      { "data": "phone_numbers.1.mobile" },
      { "data": "phone_numbers.2.branch" },
      { "data": "email" },
      { "data": "department" },
      { "data": "title" }
   ]
});
```

Alternatively if you can change data property name in JSON response from `persons` to `data`, then adding `"dataSrc": "persons"` wouldn't be needed.

#### DEMO

See [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ks5Lovxq/66/) for code and demonstration.

#### LINKS

See [jQuery DataTables: Common JavaScript console errors](https://www.gyrocode.com/articles/jquery-datatables-common-javascript-console-errors/#typeerror-cannot-read-property-length-of-undefined) for more information on this and other common console errors.

Comment: yes URL is correct on my side I was able to run the ajax, hit my controller, and my json was passing through the DataTables javascript. I  will try this as soon as I get a chance. Thanks for your feedback.